# How to mark a cell as changed so its value will be published to MDS?

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, master-data-services

I am writing some Excel VBA code to go along with the MDS add-in so our users will have an easier time sorting, filtering, and publishing data.

The code I wrote populates some cells with data from another sheet whenever the user makes a change in a certain column. The code is working and populating the correct cells with the right data; but, when I press publish the newly populated cells do not publish.

I have noticed that the cells do not change color when they are automatically populated by the procedure. Is there a procedure, method, or something that I can use on these cells to make MDS see that there has been a change so that they will be published when the publish button is pressed?

The code I am using to populate the cells looks like this:

```
Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Offset(0, 5) = Category
Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Offset(0, 7) = Style
```

Comment: Is the data being written a string? I'm surprised your not getting an error without quotation marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.

I had Application.EnableEvents set to False in the code which was preventing the cells to be marked as having changed for MDS.  I simply put "Application.EnableEvents = True" before the code that populates the cells with data.

Now the newly populated cells are highlighted and ready to be published to MDS.